# Html Select options(select dropdown) exceeds screen width when testing in iphone view

Tags: html, angular, bootstrap-4, ngx-bootstrap

I am using angular 8 bootstrap in that select drop down options width are exceeds when viewing in the i phone view. can anyone help how to solve this problem.how to design select with options for responsive mobile screen.

```
<select class="form-control col-sm-10" (change)="categorySelected($event)">
              <option selected="selected">Select an Item</option>
              <option *ngFor="let category of categories"  [value]= "category['_id']">{{category['categoryName']}}</option>
            </select>
```